# Read kernel messages page by page from screan at boot time?

Tags: boot, kernel, hardware

How can I read the messages of kernel page by page on the screan at the boot time ?
I know the "dmesg" command or /var/log ... but my box crashes before booting could have finished.
Is there any option of vmlinuz or grub to stop its messages page by page on the screen at boot time?
(I removed the boot parameters of kernel: "quiet splash", so I have a lots of msg on the screan. But the rows run away quickly.)

Comment: You might examine the output of `journalctl -b`, which uses `less` as the pager.

Comment: @CharlesGreen As I see the `journalctl` cant help at the boot time, but it very handy after boot.

Comment: Quite true - but I find the information before and after the error to be helpful as well, and the screen does scroll by quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "loglevel=4" kernel’s command-line parameter was useful to me in grub menu at start time.
With this option the "warning, notice, info, debug" lots of kernel messages was suppressed on the screen. And only all error type msgs was printed on the screen.
Here are all the kernel's parameter and other loglevel values.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html
So it was a good workaround for the original question.